# How to start a snap package

Tags: ubuntu-core, 16.04, calculator, snap

I have read some tutorials about Snapcraft and snappy and I am really excited about it.

I am using 16.04 and used `snap find` to find and install the `ubuntu-calculator-app` snap. But I don't know how to start it.

It is neither in my Dash (Unity 7) nor in my path (using zsh)

Also, I followed the instructions in this [blog post](http://www.zygoon.pl/2016/04/snappy-snapcraft-and-interfaces.html)

To create a links snap and install it. But, again, I don't know how to start the app.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just log out and log back in. If you are upgrading from an earlier version of 16.04 development release you will not have `/snap/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Great. If you can point me where in the documentation is that path it would be great.

Comment: append `PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` to end of `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Logging out and in didn't do it for me.  I had to manually add /snap/bin to my PATH in my .bashrc file.

Comment: @MarnixA.vanAmmers You should modify `$PATH` in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, not in `.bashrc`; see [*How to correctly add a path to PATH?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path).

Answer (score 11):

Snaps can be run with snap run, so for the example in the question `snap run ubuntu-calculator-app`. But that is annoying so it is better to add snaps to your path. If the app is a gui, once you open it you can right-click on the launcher icon and select add to dash.

Snaps are not in your path by default on 16.04. They are stored in /snap/bin. Since snaps are a system-wide installation it would probably be best to add this directory to your system-wide path. This is done via the file `/etc/environment`. The following can break stuff, so you should backup the file before editing it `sudo cp /etc/environment /etc/environment.bak`. Use an editor with sudo to open `/etc/environment`, and add `:/snap/bin` to the end of the PATH entry. Make sure you restart your terminal or `source /etc/environment`

If that still doesn't work, you need to make sure your user .bashrc file has added /etc/environment to its sources. `grep "source /etc/environment" ~/.bashrc` will echo that line if it exists. If it doesn't `echo "source /etc/environment" >> ~/.bashrc` will add it.

Answer (score 3):

Just including the path to the /snap/bin in the local **~/.bashrc** works for me.

*Run the following*

- `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
- `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, as Zygmunt was saying. For completeness, the other alternative is to run the app from the command line:

```
ubuntu-calculator-app.calculator
```

Check out the documentation on how to [get started with snaps on classic Ubuntu](https://developer.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-started/).