# How to use snaps via the CLI and GUI?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core

So, I have upgraded from my 15.10 to 16.04.
I have managed to install some snaps, but now I am wondering, how do I launch them? Typing their name in CLI did not help.

I tried:
ubuntu-core-launcher xkcd-webserver
But it gave me only this message:
Usage: ubuntu-core-launcher

I would like to know ways to use them both in CLI and GUI.

Comment: Not all snaps come with GUIs, you know.  Some may only be CLI, and/or need you to create .desktop launchers to launch them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the type of application. Graphical apps should be launchable from the Dash. So for example, if you install the calculator app with:

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-calculator-app
```

You should be able to:

1. Open the Dash by pressing the Super key or the Ubuntu button in the launcher
2. Start typing the first letters of "Calculator"
3. Click on the Calculator icon to launch the app

[image]

**Note**: if the icon does not appear in the Dash, you might need to [log out and log back in](https://askubuntu.com/a/759571/9781). You should only need to do this the first time after you've installed snaps support on the desktop.

Alternatively, you can launch the calculator app from the command line:

```
ubuntu-calculator-app.calculator
```

Notice the syntax is `$SNAPNAME.$COMMAND`. If `$SNAPNAME` is the same as `$COMMAND`, as a shortcut you can simply run `$SNAPNAME`

Comment: I don't see the ubuntu calculator in Dash, only the calculator that came installed. Running it from the cli gives an error, but that's a different issue. How do you know `$COMMAND`? What is it for the `xkcd-webserver`, for example?

Comment: You might need to log out and log back in, as per https://askubuntu.com/a/759571/9781. As per `xkcd-webserver`, it's a local webserver that it's supposed to start for you and then be available at http://localhost:80, but as far as I can tell, it's not working at the moment.

Comment: Confirmed as working.  For i3wm users like me, I was even able to launch it with dmenu, just type in ubuntu-calculator-app.calcuator. Good job guys :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you!