# snap libreoffice - no icons

Tags: system-installation, snap

After deinstallation of the Ubuntu standard and the installation libreoffice by

```
sudo snap install libreoffice --stable
```

there are no specific libreoffice icons as provided by normal (`*.deb`) installation for startup the different options.

I prefer in this case the installation without any further `*.deb`-packages!

How can I repair it?

Comment: It's likely not broken.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1647458

If this affects you, you should report it there.

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing to repair.**

After installing, the version of LibreOffice installed via snap can be started with the command:

`/snap/bin/libreoffice`

For more information regarding snap packages see https://snapcraft.io/

Sources:

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/snap/

[How to use snaps via the CLI and GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760167/how-to-use-snaps-via-the-cli-and-gui)

https://skyfromme.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/libreoffice-5-2-0-2-available-in-the-snap-store/

Comment: That is not the question - the launcher-icon shown are all common blue with the related option text below.

Comment: @syscon-hh I'm sorry you don't like my answer but it is indeed accurate. There is nothing to repair. Just because you expected to see the same icons in a snap package as you see in a .deb package doesn't mean that the packager was required to meet your expectations. However I suppose you could roll your own using the default icons from the deb (provided you have them) Instructions on the snapcraft.yaml file used for icon handling for snap packages can be found [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/syntax)

Comment: Canonical maintains the package, and I think its reasonable to expect icons for an office suite requiring a GUI.

Comment: @IzznogooooD Interesting. I couldn't find any information that Canonical maintained the package when I reviewed this question. A review of [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)  didn't find a snap package either.  Can you point me to where you obtained the information that the LibreOffice snap package is maintained by other than libreoffice.org? Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Well, there's: http://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-joins-the-document-foundation-s-libreoffice-project-advisory-board-506655.shtml and http://imgur.com/z784ply i guess one could speculate but i am pretty sure they are involved :)