# Starting EasyVPN Snap VPN on boot systemd

Tags: boot, bash, scripts, vpn

I have a working bash script that starts the easyvpn snap with a working config file. I want to run this script on boot so that my ubuntu core device autoconnects to my vpn on boot.

My Bash Script in /home/alexlanganke/:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "easy-openvpn.connect-server /home/alexlanganke/vpnconfig.ovpn" | bash
```

This file is naturally been made executable and has been tested successfully on its own.

My systemd Service file in /etc/systemd/system/:

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN Autostart

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/alexlanganke/autostart_vpn.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The Systemd service has been started and enabled.
Do you by chance see what I am doing wrong or missing?

journalctl -u  output:

```
Mar 27 16:50:14 localhost.localdomain autostart_vpn.sh[1373]: bash: line 1: easy-openvpn.connect-server: command not found
```

Looks to me as if the easyvpn command is not known to bash when run via systemd. Wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem arises because SystemD is run as root. The easyvpn command mentioned above is not known systemwide.

The Path can be corrected by changing the bash command to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "snap run easy-openvpn.connect-server /home/alexlanganke/vpnconfig.ovpn" | bash
```

Found the Solution with better explanation here:
[How to run a command in a snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759557/how-to-run-a-command-in-a-snap-package)

Answer (score 0):

In `terminal` type `nm-connection-editor`, open the wired/wireless connection profile where you wish to use VPN, and edit the following... changing "default_openvpn" to the path/name of your openvpn connection script...

[image]